# On CTRL+MOUSEWHEEL event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, keyboard-events, jquery-events

I was asked to implement ctrl+mousewheel event for our page site in order to change image offset on user zoom in or zoom out. I found this old answer [Override browsers CTRL+(WHEEL)SCROLL with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782040/override-browsers-ctrlwheelscroll-with-javascript) and I`ve tried to do the same.
I downloaded the [jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) for the implementation and here is my code:

```
var isCtrl = false;  
       $(document).on('keydown keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.which === 17) {
                isCtrl = e.type === 'keydown' ? true : false;
            }
        }).on('mousewheel', function(e, delta) { // `delta` will be the distance that the page would have scrolled;
            // might be useful for increasing the SVG size, might not
            if (isCtrl) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('wheel');
            }
        });
```

The events works fine separately, but if I hold the CTRL button and wheel the mouse the wheel event does not fire.
Does any one have better solution for this or may be I did something wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5cq6kt2/4/), In order for it to work you have to click in the `result` box first before trying.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) 
{
    if(event.ctrlKey == true)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(event.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
             console.log('Down');
         }else {
             console.log('Up');
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: I use `event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0` to detect up/down scroll

Comment: The `detail` was always 0 for me, so I changed your code to use `event.originalEvent.deltaY` which will be given the values `-100` or `100` depending on the direction. Not sure if that is just a problem for me, but I am posting a comment here if anyone has the same problem.

Comment: Edit for my comment: `deltaY` was not defined, so I used `wheelDelta`... To make this work in IE.

Answer (score 7):

To check if the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is clicked, the event already provides a way to do that. Try this:

```
.on('mousewheel', function(e) { 
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('wheel');
    }
});
```

This also works for `e.shiftKey`, `e.altKey` etc. I would only listen for the scroll event and there I would check if the `ctrlKey` is down.

Comment: How to check in wheel event if there is holded ctrl key by user? You can not reveal this from wheel event...

Comment: @AlexBerd Try this in the console to get a better idea: `document.body.onwheel = function(e){console.log(e.ctrlKey)}`

Comment: The way you do zomming is you hold the control button and then you wheel the mouse...try now in chrome

Comment: @AlexBerd Yes. But see the console. It's logging `true/false` if you're holding `ctrl` down or not

Comment: Yes, I see it works in the Crome, but I think you solution is not cross browser compatible

Comment: @AlexBerd it should be. Every major browser (even IE) handles this correctly

Comment: @YavorIvanov Not all browser support it, some need `DOMMouseScroll` instead of `mousewheel`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent) event, which is the standard wheel event interface to use.

```
document.getElementById('id_of_element')
         .addEventListener('wheel', (e) => { 
            if(e.ctrlKey) 
              alert("Control + mouse wheel detected!");
    })
```