# Zoom with Ctrl+Scroll Wheel in Electron App?

Tags: electron

Is it possible to emulate browser-like behavior in Electron to add zooming with ctrl+scroll wheel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible to emulate that behavior:

- Catch the CTRL + mousewheel element [as discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782040/override-browsers-ctrlwheelscroll-with-javascript).
- Use the [Electron web-frame API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-frame.md) to adapt the zoomFactor accordingly, use `webFrame.getZoomFactor()` to get the current zoom level and `webFrame.setZoomFactor(level)` to change it.